# Crystal reports ; How to change the format of a field

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I'm very new to crystal reports so please bear with me

I have created a report. The report connects to a SQL server database. One of the field is a date field but set as a varchar type and looks like this `19890105`.

I want to change it to this format `05/01/1989`

I tried this

```
CDate (
(ToNumber ({ELEC_.DOB_DROIT} [1 to 4])),
(ToNumber ({ELEC_.DOB_DROIT} [5 to 6])),
(ToNumber ({ELEC_.DOB_DROIT} [7 to 8]))
)
```

I've put it my formula editor (see below)

[image]

I'm doing a preview of the report and the date is still in the format of  `yyyymmdd` ...

I'm missing something but I'm unsure of what ...

TIA for your insights ...

**Update since yesterday**: I found a solution since yesterday but I still would like an answer , out of curiosity and who knows, I might be able to use it in the near future. Thanks.

Comment: If your character data is really "1989 01 05" with blanks, that is 10 characters long; then your offsets in your formula are not taking that into account; you would want 1 to 4, 6 to 7, and 9 to 10.

Comment: Hi @MarkStewart I've double checked and the initial format is `19890105`

Comment: That formula converts it to a date. Right click on the field/formula and pick the display format from there.

Comment: the order is cdate(yyyy,mm,dd) so make sure you really want `jan 5, 1989` also

Comment: Hi @shawnt00 what do you mean `pick the display format from there`?

Comment: Hi @JamieD77 I want `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: I mean that all your formatting options are available from the "Properties" dialog (or whatever it's called.) Format Editor?

Comment: @shawnt00 a screen capture would be great ...

Comment: This is from Google: https://www.blackbaud.com/images/support/kb/bb561a.gif

Comment: got it @shawnt00 I have a format editor but I don't have time. This is a varchar field ....

Comment: If that formula worked then you converted it to a date. Put the formula on the report and use that rather than the raw database column.

Comment: @Andy Perhaps I misread your comment. "I don't have time." normally means you're in a rush but I realized you might have meant you don't have a "time" tab in the format editor. Post a screenshot of your report design or at least explain what you thought that formula was supposed to do.

Comment: sorry Shawnt I seemed to have stepped on your toes with my response .. deleted.

Comment: @shawnt00 sorry for the misunderstanding :) You got it correctly. I don't have the time tab. I will have to reformulate my question , but it will be tomorrow because it is evening here and the miss is waiting ... I will give you update tomorrow. Thanks again

Comment: The picture ShawnT sent you showed time because he was formatting a DateTime type field as an example.. You will not see time because yours is a Date type field only. If you were formatting a time type field you would only see time

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for your patience yesterday eve. I mused quite a bit yesterday eve on why the function did not work out. So I looked on the internet today and I found out a solution:

I created a sql function that did the work. Issue is that I now have performance issue. It takes 10s to fetch 12K records.

My solution will do the trick but out of curiosity, I would still like to have an answer for my question

Comment: You were given the solution yesterday. If you created a formula with CDate function and it successfully provided data to your report WITHOUT an error then there is no reason you cant change the date format as explained by ShawnT above. Do not let the fact that the example provided showed time in the available formats confuse the issue. SQL is a good work around but its not needed and as you have experienced it will slow your report down.

Comment: Actually it shouldn't slow your report down if it is included IN the original query. If you insist on using the SQL solution, go back to your original report without the command you created. View the SQL and copy that into a new command query. then add the case statement below as an additional output field.

Comment: Hi @CoSpringsGuy the solution given yesterday did not work. I did `CDATE({Elec_My_Table.DOB_DROIT})` in the formula and nothing has changed. I still have `yyyymmdd` format style and I cannot see the time tab like you showed me yesterday. Concerning my solution, it is far from perfect but it is working. Your advice is a good one. If you can find "the other" solution, the ones that use crystal reports own syntax, I would be greatful.

Comment: I dont understand why you are concerned with "time tab"? When you place the formula that uses the CDATE function and right cick.. then select  format field is there not a tab for date with several different formatting options?

Comment: @CoSpringsGuy short answer : No. Long one: When I was talking about the time tab, I meant the tab for date with several different formatting options and no, it is not appearing...

Comment: Thats odd.. What version of Crystal Reports are you using? I just duplicated what you are trying to do and cannot see why this would be an issue for you.

Comment: @CoSpringsGuy CR2008 v `12.0.0.683`

Comment: Should work fine .. As I said I emulated your issue with the following formula and it worked fine .. CDATE(
tonumber("19890105" [1 to 4]),
tonumber("19890105" [5 to 6]),
tonumber("19890105" [7 to 8])
) Sorry I couldnt help

Comment: @CoSpringsGuy This is plain insane. Your trick worked fine. I have `05/01/1989`... grrrhhh Yet , when Regardless, probably something with my db... I give you the point. I owe you for your precious time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why I didnt think of this before

```
totext(
CDate (
(ToNumber ({ELEC_.DOB_DROIT} [1 to 4])),
(ToNumber ({ELEC_.DOB_DROIT} [5 to 6])),
(ToNumber ({ELEC_.DOB_DROIT} [7 to 8]))
),"dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find my answer / workaround in SQL

I went through the `database expert`, add `another command` and put that sql query

```
 SELECT iu_ent,CONVERT(varchar(10),CAST(DOB_DROIT AS DATE),103) AS DOB_DROIT,
        CASE 
            WHEN DOB_DROIT_CONJ = '' THEN ''
            ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10),CAST(DOB_DROIT_CONJ AS DATE),103) END AS DOB_DROIT_CONJ 
FROM Elec_My_Table
```

It is a bit long (10s for 12k rows) but my table is not a big one

And this one is my final solution all in CR's language

```
stringVar DateNaissED := if isnull({ELEC_.DOB_DROIT}) then '' else {ELEC_.DOB_DROIT};

IF DateNaissED = '' THEN ''
ELSE
right(DateNaissED,2) + '/' + mid(DateNaissED,5,2) + '/' + left(DateNaissED,4)
```